# unique_ptr<char[]> confusion

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a class in which I would like one of the functions to pass a unique ptr object to a char array. But I'm confused on several on features of unique pointers. I'm aware a destructor is called automatically when there are no more references to the object but is still the same for primitive variables? For instance if I do this, will the memory be deleted?

```cpp
class A {
private:
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<char[]> data) {
        data = nullptr;
    }
    ~A();

};
int main() {
    auto data = std::make_unique<char[]>(10);
    A a(std::move(data));
    return 0;
 }
```

The next question I have is: If I have a private object which I want to point to data, why does this result in a compiler error?

```cpp
class A {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> internaldata;
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<char[]> data) {
        internaldata = data;
    }
    ~A() {
        internaldata = nullptr;
    }

};
int main() {
    auto data = std::make_unique<char[]>(10);
    A a(std::move(data));
    return 0;
 }
```

However when I call std::move while assigning it, the code compiles fine.

```cpp
class A {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> internaldata;
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<char[]> data) {
        internaldata = std::move(data);
    }
    ~A() {
        internaldata = nullptr;
    }

};
int main() {
    auto data = std::make_unique<char[]>(10);
    A a(std::move(data));
    return 0;
 }
```

But why do I have to call std::move twice here? Once for passing the argument then the second for assigning? And what exactly occurs in terms of reference count during that process, does a reallocation, copy and deletion occur?

And finally, is it possible to pass data into the smart pointer during the deceleration? Because currently I do it like this:

```cpp
    auto data = std::make_unique<char[]>(10);
    char* buf = data.get();
    strcpy(buf, "hello\0");
```

But is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```cpp
    char hellobuffer[] = "hello";
    auto data = std::make_unique<char[]>(hellobuffer);
```

Where data is automatically assigned the correct size needed to store hellobuffer and copies over the data itself?

Comment: Use `std::string` and make your life significantly easier. Since you're already using stl constructs, there is no rational reason - or at least none represented in your code - for using `char[]` vs `std::string`. Also, I doubt that `unique_ptr` is going to `delete[]` the buffer rather than just `delete`ing it. (BUT, I haven't traced it to be sure.)

Comment: The reason I won't use std::string is because ultimately I want to store and send binary data across a network. So a char[] buffer is optimal.

Comment: `char[]` is not optimal. Why makes you think that? `BYTE*` or `unsigned char*` would make WAY more sense.

Comment: Because as far as I'm aware, std::string holds character arrays with null terminators. Correct me if I'm wrong but binary data should not be stored in std::strings. And by char[] I technically meant u/byte the char[] here is just an example.

Comment: Binary data should not be stored in `std::string`s. It should also not, in C++, be stored in `char[]`.

Comment: That was just an example for my question.

Comment: Okay, I get that - but your example makes any potential solution applicable to your example invalid for your real use case. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I know what an xy problem is. I know if it had to do explicitly with strings I would have asked for strings. I know what an std::string does, I know what an std::vector does, I know for strings those are both viable solutions and even for binary data std::vector is a viable solution but this question is specifically about std::unique_ptr<char[]> so please keep it on topic..

Comment: @3Dave Yes, there is a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` specialization which does `delete[] p` instead of `delete p` (among other differences).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm aware a destructor is called automatically when there are no more references to the object but is still the same for primitive variables?

The destructor is always logically called. However, since things like `int` and `char` are trivially-destructible, the compiler understands that nothing should actually get called.

> For instance if I do this, will the memory be deleted?

Yes -- the whole point of `std::unique_ptr<T>` is that your memory is taken care of automatically.

```
A(std::unique_ptr<char[]> data) {
    internaldata = data;
}
```

That example fails to compile because `internaldata = data` is calling the copy-assignment operator and copying `std::unique_ptr` instances is disallowed (hence the unique bit).

> And what exactly occurs in terms of reference count during that process, does a reallocation, copy and deletion occur?

There is no reference count -- a `std::unique_ptr` either refers to something or it is empty. When you `std::move` from a `std::unique_ptr`, the moved-from variable becomes empty. If you are looking for a reference-counted pointer type, see [`std::shared_ptr<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

> And finally, is it possible to pass data into the smart pointer during the deceleration?

No. For `std::make_unique<T[]>`, you are only allowed to pass a `std::size_t` (see [overload 2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)). It should be easy to write a wrapper function for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you that answers all my questions.